How to add types to pandas *DataFrames*?
Pandas dataframes are useful, but they are fundamentally untyped. With this I don't mean the raw types of the columns, but the structure of the dataframe itself.
For example, when you do df : pd.Dataframe = pd.read_csv(...), you don't know which columns the dataframe contains, nor what their types are. You know them at runtime, of course (df.columns, etc.) but that doesn't help the type checker.
When writing code, you cannot enforce the 'type' of the dataframe, defined as the number and names of columns, the type of such columns, etc. - you only have a black box pd.Dataframe structure which is too generic to be of any actual typing use.
So what is the solution people use? Is there a library which allows to enforce better structure? Or do yo use custom classes to wrap over operations? (the latter seems like heavy work).
Any ideas / alternative solutions?

To clarify, I want the type checker to enforce this at 'compile' time, not runtime checks. I want to be able to look at a dataframe and have pylance or something else tell me which column it contains, and emit a compile error if I try to access a column which was not explicitly specified in the type. For example:
df: pd.Dataframe[{'col1': pd.int64, 'col2': pd.string}] = pd.read_csv(...)
df.col3 ## Raise *type* error at *compile* time, not runtime.
df.columns['X']    ## Editor autocompletes 'X' to 'col1' or 'col2'
df.col1.tolower() ## *Type* error at compile time


You can specify the names of the columns to read in with the usecols parameter and the types of the columns with dtypes. What else are you looking for? I think it would help to include a couple of lines of an example csv file and how you expect it to be read in.

@SamR Thank you! I want the type checker to enforce this at 'compile' time, not runtime checks. I want to be able to look at a dataframe and have pylance or something else tell me which column it contains, and emit a compile error if I try to access a column which was not explicitly specified in the type.
Let me add an example

Right I understand now - sounds like maybe you're looking for something like pandera or pandas-stubs though I'm not sure how well they work with autocomplete in various IDEs.

This may be nitpicking, but I would not call this adding types to DataFrames, but rather enforcing a schema on a DataFrame, analogous to JSON and JSON Schema, for example. This maybe leads you to tools like the already mentioned pandera. But maybe I also misunderstood your question/intent.

@SamR IIUC pandas-stubs only adds typing to functions / classes which pandas doesn't currently have. Pandera however looks like what I am looking for, thank you very much! Feel free to add an answer and I will accept it :)

@simon No that's a fair point. I don't know if the terminology is correct, or schema is more adequate, but in my mind this is still about typing. JSON too - ok technically annotating a variable as 'JSON' type is a 'type annotation', but JSON is too general, so it doesn't give a lot of info. Annotating a python variable as 'Object' is also technically correct, but useless. JSON and Dataframe are similar, as they are too generic for the type annotation to be very useful. Anyway, thank you - pandera looks to be the right solution!

Usually I don't like the Stack Overflow search, but it was actually pretty good in this case - [python] [dataframe] static type checking if you're curious.
